# Drupal security measures

Tags: 7, security

I have got a list of security violations for my website from security team. It says

> Cookie without HttpOnly flag set
>
> Autocomplete Password Enabled

So, what is this basically? Can I overcome this in my Drupal 7 site?

Comment: You got two comments which answered the separate questions, but both seem right to me. For the autocomplete password enabled - check out http://drupal.org/project/pci_update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask for the actual security report.  They often contain explanations about what the problem really is, as well as offering a solution.

I believe this will take care of the password autocomplete issue; I have a client who requires this and have it deployed on a few sites.

```
function mymodule_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  // http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/disabling-autocomplete-forms

  if ($form['#id'] == 'user-login') {
    $form['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
  }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, there's now a very small module that does this, called PCI Update (https://drupal.org/project/pci_update). It also turns off autocomplete on the login *block*.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for `session.cookie_httponly` (you should set this flag to true in your `php.ini` file):

> Marks the cookie as accessible only through the HTTP protocol. 
>   This means that the cookie won't be accessible by scripting languages, such as JavaScript. 
>   This setting can effectively help to reduce identity theft through XSS attacks 
>   (although it is not supported by all browsers).

Check out [the documentation for `session.cookie_httponly`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly).

Comment: You can also do this via an ini_set() in your settings.php if you don't want to make a gloabl change.

Comment: @MPD - Yes and you could also use a `php_flag` directive in a `.htaccess` file.